# Plupload Ajax sending POST information Jquery - CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, plupload

I am trying to store the information about uploaded images and videos to the database. I am using PLupload custom script to upload the files. The upload proces is working well with custom filenames. Jquery is loaded as well as the plupload scripts.

In the FileUploaded section I am trying to use a Jquery $.ajax or $.post to send the data to the controller.

```
FileUploaded: function(upldr, file, object, ordernumber, orderitem) {               
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller.php",
        data: {
           file: file,
           ordernumber: ordernumber,
           orderitem: orderitem 
        },
        success: function(results){
           document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "[ Stored in database ]";
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });

},
```

But I am getting a strange error: Uncaught TypeError: this.getSource is not a function in plupload.full.min.js. I have searched for hours now on Stackoverflow and Google but wasn't able to find a answer.

I hope that I can find the answers here. I tried $.post as well without success. Any other suggestions to parse the information to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the post function of jQuery

```js
$.post( "controller.php", { file: file, ordernumber: ordernumber, orderitem: orderitem })
  .done(function( data ) {
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "[ Stored in database ]";
  });
```

Comment: This worked indeed as expected. Thank you for answering!

Comment: with pleasure dude

Answer (score 0):

After posting this I also found out why the information didn't parse through. The JSON string wasn't fully compatible. With this it worked:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "controller.php",
                data: {
                    "file": file,
                    "ordernumber": ordernumber, 
                    "orderitem": orderitem
                },
                success: function(results){
                    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "[ Stored in database ]";
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
```